# Seaborn FacetGrid: Make axes intersect in (0, 0)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn's `FacetGrid` to scatterplot a data frame.
Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])

fig = sns.FacetGrid(data=df)
fig.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')
```

[image]

This makes the axes intersect at the bottom left of the plot. I want them to intersect at (0, 0). In Matplotlib, I would do that with the `set_position()` function of the spines. But I could not find out how to access that function via Seaborn. 
How can I change where the axes intersect in my plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying question seems to be: How to get the matplotlib `Axes` from seaborn's `FacetGrid` object?

If `g = seaborn.FacetGrid(...)`, then `g.axes` is a numpy array of `Axes`. Here you have a single subplot, hence the array's only item is the axes to look for,

```
ax = g.axes[0,0]
```

From thereon you may use the known solution to set the spine position via  `set_position`, as shown e.g. in [the spine placement demo](http://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')

ax = g.axes[0,0]
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

plt.show()
```

[image]